# I've badly messed up my apache configuration, how do I perform a full reset?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apache-http-server

I am a very lazy person, I do not want to know how to properly configure or fix my apache server. How do I **completely obliterate any and every apache related file on my machine**, to be able to start over fresh?

Comment: `apt-get purge apache2`, then reinstall.

Comment: @bwDraco Well that worked unexpectedly well, last time I tried that my config files wouldn't go away :o